# Redux: Using Spread Operator on 2D array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, spread-syntax

New to React.js, I am having hard time using the spread operator in my reducers to update my state that has an 2D-array property.

For instance initial state is so:

```
let initialState = {
    grid: new Array(5).fill(new Array(5).fill(0)),
    player: { coords: [2,3], health: 100 }
}
```

After binding the action, lets say the payload goes to **PRESS_LEFT**

```
case PRESS_LEFT: {
  let oldCoords = [state.player.coords[0], state.player.coords[1]];
  let newCoords = [state.player.coords[0], state.player.coords[1]-1];
  let thereIsWall = validateWall(state.grid, newCoords);
  if (thereIsWall){
    return state
  } else{
    return{
      ...state,
      player: { ...state.player, coords: newCoords },
      grid: { ...state.grid, state.grid[oldCoords[0]][oldCoords[1]] = 1 }
    }
  }
}
```

I am able to update the player's state, but not the grid. Essentially I want to update the coordinates from `oldCoords` and assign it to 1.

Answer (score 1):

its because the old value is assigned to null

let initialState = {
    grid: new Array(5).fill(new Array(5).fill(0)),
    player: { **coords: null,** health: 100 }
}

and then you are trying to read zeroth index of null, that will throw the error.

```
let oldCoords = [state.player.coords[0], state.player.coords[1]];
```

**Update:**

grid is an array but you are returning the object ..change to below syntax

```
grid: [ ...state.grid, state.grid[oldCoords[0]][oldCoords[1]]=1 ]
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot edit my post where players.coords is already initialized when action is dispatched.