# Need to append data in the array in reducer of redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am doing pagination where i will be getting data for each page click.I want to append the data with the previous values.Here is my current code.Have no idea to do it.

```
const InitialProjects={
    projectList:[],
    error:null,
    loading:false
}

export const projects=(state=InitialProjects,action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
        case ActionTypes.FETCH_PROJECTS:
            return Object.assign({},state,{
                projectList:[],error:null,loading:true
            })
        case ActionTypes.FETCH_PROJECTS_SUCCESS:
            return {
                projectList:action.payload

            }
        case ActionTypes.FETCH_PROJECTS_FAILURE:
            return Object.assign({},state,{
                projectList:["not-found"],error:action.payload.message||action.payload.status,loading:false
            })
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

My first response will look something like this

```
[
{
  Id:0,
Name:india
},
{
Id:1,
Name:bang
},
{
Id:3,
Name:us
},
{
 Id:5,
Name:uk
}
]
```

second response will be like this

```
   [
    {
      Id:8,
    Name:india
    },
    {
    Id:12,
    Name:bang
    },
    {
    Id:19,
    Name:us
    },
    {
     Id:35,
    Name:uk
    }
    ]
```

Please do note that the id field might not be consecutive.
I want something like this in my redux

```
projectList:
0(pin): {Id:1,Name:'dewd'}
1(pin): {Id:2,Name:'tyytg'}
2(pin): {Id:5,Name:'xsx'}
3(pin): {Id:4,Name:'tyyt'}
4(pin): {Id:10,Name:'xsx'}
5(pin): {Id:17,Name:'xsx'}
```

Appreciate any help.Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redux: Using Spread Operator on 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40393624/redux-using-spread-operator-on-2d-array)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can spread the results on each success.

```
case ActionTypes.FETCH_PROJECTS:
  return {
    ...state,
    error: null,
    loading: true,
  }
case ActionTypes.FETCH_PROJECTS_SUCCESS:
   return {
     ...state,
     projectList: [...state.projectList, ...action.payload]
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Hemerson. I m getting error near ...state as Unexpected token.

Comment: Thanks..I added babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread and now there is no error.But when i retreive the response the previous values are getting replaced by the new ones!!!

Comment: remove `projectList:[]` from `case ActionTypes.FETCH_PROJECTS:` and than it should work :)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the object spread operator doesn't work in your case. So an `ES5` version of the answer for you would be.

```
    case ActionTypes.FETCH_PROJECTS_SUCCESS:
       return Object.assign(
                {}, 
                state, 
                { 
                   projectList: state.projectList.concat(action.payload)
                });
```

This copies all the previous values from `state` into a new object by using `Object.assign` then overwrites a new `projectList` property by concatenating old values from `state.projectList` and new ones from `action.payload`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: What if the projectList was an object ? how to shallow merge the two objects without overriding keys?

Comment: If `projectList` was an object you would essentially need an additional `Object.assign` instead of `.concat`. If you need to shallow merge objects without overriding you should interchange the order of 2nd and 3rd arguments to `Object.assign`.

Comment: As far as I read how `Object.assign` works , it diffs the root level keys of objects and returns a new object with unique keys, interchanging objects will always override the first object in order. console this : 

    const a= {1:1,2:2};const b={1:3,2:2};console.log(Object.assign({},a,b));console.log(Object.assign({},b,a));

 
Thanks for the help anyway

Comment: Well yes, that's how it works. When you interchange the order the root level keys of the first object (which is now technically the second) are not overridden by the same root level keys in the second object. Isn't that you wanted or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: Nope , I wanted to keep both keys redundant inside the new Object assigned . I have already made a transformer function to transform my response objects into array to be consumed inside the store , and the reducer will simply concat the incoming transformed array into the store again .

Thanks for the help anyway.